# React/Redux updating state but re-rendering not updating graph data

Tags: javascript, react-redux, recharts

I'm working in a project that consists on having different tabs where in each tab we can see a graph which shows the data obtained via a call to an API. (each tab(graph) is doing a `ComponentDidMount()` to obtained the concerned data).

Given the fact that I want to be able to filter the data by the run_id(**job_name**) of the model which generates the data, I have added a dropdown menu which allows to select a particular **job_name**, which is added to the end of the URL in the `ComponentDidMount()` to select only the data of a realised job. The aim is to show the graph of the data of this job automatically.

Here we can see the `ComponentDidMount()` I'm using every time I want to pass all the data to the graph function.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const jobName = this.props.jobName;
    this.props.getFuelPrices(`http://localhost:8000/data/stack/fuel/${jobName}`);
  }
```

where `getFUelPrices(url)` is the call to the API

The structure of the main page is:

```
class Stack extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            tabActive: 'fuel-price',
            jobName: 'julia-stacking-model-test-f353caae-729b-4a0a-b0f7-7640b4f4f1f9',
        };
    }

    handleSubmit = event => event.preventDefault();
    handleOnChange = (e) => {
                              this.setState({
                                jobName: e.target.value,
                              })
                            };
```

Here in `handleOnChange()` is where we are selecting the new job from the dropdown list.

```
render () {
      if(!this.props.user || this.props.user.role < this.props.acl)
          return <AccedDenied />
      return (


          <div className="Stack">

            <BreadCrumb />

            <div className="card-box">
              <div className="test" style={{margin: "20px"}}>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form-inline">

                  <label style={{marginLeft: '20px'}}>
                    Select Job:
                    <JobNames onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
                  </label>

                  <label style={{marginLeft: '20px'}}>
                    Compare with job:
                    <JobNames />
                  </label>

                </form>
              </div>
              <TradesTabs
                data={[
                  {
                    key: 'fuel-price',
                    label: 'Fuel Price',
                    action: () => this.setState({ tabActive: 'fuel-price'}),
                  },
                  {
                    key: 'total-stack',
                    label: 'Total Stack',
                    action: () => this.setState({ tabActive: 'total-stack' }),
                  }, ..........


            active={this.state.tabActive}
            />

            <div className="tab-content">
              {this.state.tabActive === 'fuel-price' ? <TotalFuelPrice jobName={this.state.jobName}/> : console.log("not showing fuel price graph", this.state.jobName)}
              {this.state.tabActive === 'total-stack' ? <TotalStack jobName={this.state.jobName}/> : console.log("not showing total stack graph", this.state.jobName)}
              {this.state.tabActive === 'nuclear' ? <TotalNuclear jobName={this.state.jobName}/> : console.log("not showing nuclear graph", this.state.jobName)}
              {this.state.tabActive === 'solarwind' ? <TotalSolarWind jobName={this.state.jobName}/> : console.log("not showing solarwind graph", this.state.jobName)}
              {this.state.tabActive === 'hydro' ? <TotalHydro jobName={this.state.jobName}/> : console.log("not showing solarwind graph", this.state.jobName)}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

So here I'm sending the selected JobName to the different **TotalComponents** which they do the `ComponentDidMount()` call to the API and the graph generation.

NEVERTHELESS, when I'm doing this, I'm getting my state correctly updated but my graph is not showing the new data unless I refresh the app. To be more precise, when selecting an option from the dropdown menu:

```
class JobNames extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getJobNames('http://localhost:8000/data/stack/getJobs');
  }

  render() {

    let jobs = this.props.jobname;
    let optionItems = jobs.map((job) =>
            <option key={job.name}>{job.name}</option>
        );

    return (
      <div>
         <select className="form-control" style={{marginLeft: '8px'}} onChange={this.props.onChange}>
            {optionItems}
         </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My graph is doing a re-render because line colors are changing due to a Math.random function for selecting the colors, but the data of the graph is not updating automatically.

I know it is not the best explanaiton ever, but I've tried to be as clear as possible. Don't hesitate to ask for more details or asking questions.

How can I solve this problem? The aim is to pick an option from the dropdown menu and to get automatically the new graph displayed.

The graph component is:

```
class FuelPriceGraph extends Component {

  render(){
    {
    const COLORS = ['   #ff0000','#ffff00','#00ffff','#ff00ff','#00ff00','#cc33ff','#f81e46','#3ea6e3','#f31ac9','#a6fbc7','#01d128', '#3dfc92','#4965e0', '#ef6a0c','#f81108','#f3f609', '#6e23fb', '#cf22c2', '#5aeef7', '#a1fd20','#9babe3', '#fa6c45','#e74885','#dc0508'];
    let json = this.props.data;
    console.log("the data for is" ,json);

    return (
      <div className="FuelPriceGraph">
        <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" aspect={5 / 1}>
          <LineChart width={800} height={350}>
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
            <XAxis dataKey="date" type="category" allowDuplicatedCategory={false} />
            <YAxis dataKey="price"/>
            <Tooltip/>
            <Legend />
            {json.map(s => {
                let color = COLORS[Math.floor(Math.random() * COLORS.length)];
                let type = (s.scenario === "mean-scenario") ? "5 5" : "" ;
                return <Line dataKey="price" data={s.data} name={s.scenario} key={s.scenario} stroke={color} strokeDasharray={type}/>
                }
            )}

          </LineChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
      </div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your component only mounts once; if you then change a prop for it (such as an id) you won't get the mount again, you'll get a componentWillReceiveProps, componentDidReceiveProps.

Comment: Thanks you @ChrisCousins Using componentDidUpdate() resolve the problem

Comment: Glad to hear it!, do you want me to make that into a solution? It may be a good idea for others reading this to show how you modified your code to work.

Comment: Yes, feel you free to do it. Sharing it is always a good idea. Thanks @ChrisCousins